# A Problem in Running Pspicture Environment

Tags: pstricks, pspicture

My problem is: I drew a picture in  Latexdraw software and when I run the latex code of my picture in my editor, lots of errors made. I use TexLive 2017 and my editor is bidiTexmaker. My code is:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}   

 \usepackage{amsmath,verbatim,epsfig,graphicx,amssymb} 
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{helvet}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} 
 \usepackage{pst-plot}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{pspicture}(0,-1.212)(3.07325,1.212)
 \definecolor{color509}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.2}
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(0.06625,0.6)(0.88625,0.6)
 \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
 \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
 \usefont{T1}{ptm}{b}{it}
 \psframe[linewidth=0.024,dimen=outer](2.04625,1.02)(0.88625,0.2)
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm](2.86625,1.2)(2.86625,0.0)
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm](0.06625,1.2)(0.06625,0.0)
 \psdots[dotsize=0.374,dotstyle=oplus](2.86625,0.6)
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(2.06625,0.6)(2.66625,0.6)
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm,linecolor=color509](0.06625,0.0)(2.86625,-1.2)
 \psline[linewidth=0.024cm,linecolor=color509](2.86625,0.0)(0.06625,-1.2)
 \end{pspicture}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

The picture of errors are:

[image]

I would very much appreciate any assistance you can offer me in this question.

**Edition:** I want to ask you to guide to improve the code until that the picture  inside an ellipse as follows. Thanks

[image]

Comment: use `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Wonderful. Really Really Thanks. It works. Please write your comment as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Well, you set `linecolor=...` It's used in your code.

Comment: These extravagant coordinates come from Latex Draw?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. It is extracted from  Latex Draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xelatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3)(3.5,3)
    \pnodes(-2.7,3){A}(-2.7,1){B}(-2.7,0){C}(2.7,-3){D}
    \pnodes(2.7,3){A'}(2.7,1){B'}(2.7,0){C'}(-2.7,-3){D'}
    \pnodes(-1,1){X}(1,1){Y}
    \rput(B'){\circlenode{P}{$+$}}
    \psline(A)(C)(D)
    \ncline{A'}{P}
    \ncline{P}{C'}
    \ncline{C'}{D'}
    \psframe(-1,0)(1,2)
    \ncline{->}{B}{X}
    \ncline{->}{Y}{P}
    \psellipse[linecolor=green](0,.5)(3.5,2.25)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question. Please see it . Thanks

Comment: Its perfect. Never I use the  Latexdraw software. In fact, I want to write  pspicture codes as you done. Thanks again.

Comment: I used command  \psellipse[ellipsecolor=Green](0,.5)(3.5,2.25) but dose not work.

Comment: @user0410: `linecolor=green`.

Comment: I suggest to change your username, since you are not "Artificial Stupidity" . In fact, you are "Factual Knowledge". Please excuse me if my suggestion bother you.

Comment: @user0410: Changing birth certificate takes time and money. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt,12pt]{standalone}   
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3)(3.5,3)
    \psline(-2.7,3)(-2.7,1)(-2.7,0)(2.7,-3)
    \cnodeput(2.7,1){P}{$+$}
    \pnodes(-2.7,1){A}(2.7,3){B0}(2.7,0){B1}
    \ncline{B0}{P}\ncline{P}{B1}
    \psline(B1)(-2.7,-3)
    \fnode[framesize=1.5](0,1){F}{}
    \ncline{->}{A}{F}\ncline{->}{F}{P}
    \psellipse[linecolor=green,fillcolor=green,
               opacity=0.15,fillstyle=solid](0,.5)(3.5,2.25)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would  appreciate for your nice code.